# How do I solve this reccurence relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sqrt{f(x)+1}=f(x+1)$
I don't have the knowledge to begin to solve for this however I know that the limit of this function is at the golden ratio $1.618\ldots$ could someone walk me through it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm playing around. My bad, last typo I hope.

Comment: I think the RHS should be just $f(x),$ in which case you get $f^2-f-1=0$ which leads to $f=\phi$ as the only positive root.

Comment: Of course for $x$ large, $f(x+1)\approx f(x),$ so may be ok as is.

Comment: Yes I meant f(x+1) on RHS as I placed.

Comment: Anyone know how to solve for f(x)

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to also say $f(0)=0$? Then $f(1)=\sqrt1$, and $f(2)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt1}$, and $f(3)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt1}}$, etc. I doubt there's a nice formula besides just saying:$$f(n)=\underbrace{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dotsb\sqrt1}}}_{n\text{ sqrt signs}}$$

Comment: And, if we define $“f(\infty)”$ to mean $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to\infty}f(N)$, then yes, $f(\infty)=\phi$ (the golden ratio).

Comment: What if f(0)=c (some constant)

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Same thing, just $f(n)=\underbrace{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dotsb\sqrt c}}}_{n\text{ sqrt signs}}$... I still doubt that there is a nice closed formula. Unless $f(0)=\phi$, in which case $f(x)=\phi$ for all $x$.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page may interest you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical)

Comment: Thanks lots, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @columbus8myhw See also https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/7/b/c7b844c14d785992d33f0a62a8964dff.png